# How to load data from a txt file with variable number of columns in each row into a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, file-handling

My data file looks like this:

[image]

I want to load this data into a numpy array. How do I do that?

If I use `loadtxt(filename)`, it gives the error:

```
raise ValueError(errmsg)
ValueError: Some errors were detected !
```

If I use `genfromtxt(filename, delimiter=" ")`, it gives the same error, even though this was supposed to fix it.

If I use the following:

```
from array import array
N=84 # max number of columns in any row in the data file
with open('C:/Users/hp1/Desktop/ClusterAnalysis/hierarchical_result.txt',"r") as f:
        all_data=[x.split() for x in f.readlines()]
        a=array([map(int,x) for x in all_data[:N]])
```

I get this error:

`TypeError: array() argument 1 must be a unicode character, not list`

**EDIT:** This is all of the data in the data file:

```
61 81
2 28
13 31
59 64
36 63
45 58
3 73
47 51
33 68
1 72
12 84
3 73 12 84
1 72 3 73 12 84
6 83
27 42
66 6 83
54 77
60 54 77
39 40
10 19
49 79
22 76
61 81 60 54 77
65 61 81 60 54 77
8 65 61 81 60 54 77
66 6 83 8 65 61 81 60 54 77
71 47 51
18 25
59 64 18 25
32 59 64 18 25
11 34
20 26
27 42 20 26
69 27 42 20 26
16 62
43 16 62
30 45 58
85 30 45 58
56 85 30 45 58
17 11 34
22 76 32 59 64 18 25
29 39 40
14 57
44 14 57
7 24
78 2 28
15 37
70 15 37
48 70 15 37
80 29 39 40
4 9
75 43 16 62
13 31 75 43 16 62
74 13 31 75 43 16 62
36 63 17 11 34
53 36 63 17 11 34
46 1 72 3 73 12 84
23 52
38 66 6 83 8 65 61 81 60 54 77
82 38 66 6 83 8 65 61 81 60 54 77
10 19 56 85 30 45 58
33 68 10 19 56 85 30 45 58
5 49 79
78 2 28 4 9
55 80 29 39 40
67 55 80 29 39 40
7 24 67 55 80 29 39 40
35 48 70 15 37
69 27 42 20 26 35 48 70 15 37
41 82 38 66 6 83 8 65 61 81 60 54 77
50 69 27 42 20 26 35 48 70 15 37
33 68 10 19 56 85 30 45 58 41 82 38 66 6 83 8 65 61 81 60 54 77
7 24 67 55 80 29 39 40 50 69 27 42 20 26 35 48 70 15 37
46 1 72 3 73 12 84 33 68 10 19 56 85 30 45 58 41 82 38 66 6 83 8 65 61 81 60 54 77
22 76 32 59 64 18 25 46 1 72 3 73 12 84 33 68 10 19 56 85 30 45 58 41 82 38 66 6 83 8 65 61 81 60 54 77
7 24 67 55 80 29 39 40 50 69 27 42 20 26 35 48 70 15 37 22 76 32 59 64 18 25 46 1 72 3 73 12 84 33 68 10 19 56 85 30 45 58 41 82 38 66 6 83 8 65 61 81 60 54 77
53 36 63 17 11 34 7 24 67 55 80 29 39 40 50 69 27 42 20 26 35 48 70 15 37 22 76 32 59 64 18 25 46 1 72 3 73 12 84 33 68 10 19 56 85 30 45 58 41 82 38 66 6 83 8 65 61 81 60 54 77
78 2 28 4 9 53 36 63 17 11 34 7 24 67 55 80 29 39 40 50 69 27 42 20 26 35 48 70 15 37 22 76 32 59 64 18 25 46 1 72 3 73 12 84 33 68 10 19 56 85 30 45 58 41 82 38 66 6 83 8 65 61 81 60 54 77
74 13 31 75 43 16 62 78 2 28 4 9 53 36 63 17 11 34 7 24 67 55 80 29 39 40 50 69 27 42 20 26 35 48 70 15 37 22 76 32 59 64 18 25 46 1 72 3 73 12 84 33 68 10 19 56 85 30 45 58 41 82 38 66 6 83 8 65 61 81 60 54 77
44 14 57 74 13 31 75 43 16 62 78 2 28 4 9 53 36 63 17 11 34 7 24 67 55 80 29 39 40 50 69 27 42 20 26 35 48 70 15 37 22 76 32 59 64 18 25 46 1 72 3 73 12 84 33 68 10 19 56 85 30 45 58 41 82 38 66 6 83 8 65 61 81 60 54 77
5 49 79 44 14 57 74 13 31 75 43 16 62 78 2 28 4 9 53 36 63 17 11 34 7 24 67 55 80 29 39 40 50 69 27 42 20 26 35 48 70 15 37 22 76 32 59 64 18 25 46 1 72 3 73 12 84 33 68 10 19 56 85 30 45 58 41 82 38 66 6 83 8 65 61 81 60 54 77
71 47 51 5 49 79 44 14 57 74 13 31 75 43 16 62 78 2 28 4 9 53 36 63 17 11 34 7 24 67 55 80 29 39 40 50 69 27 42 20 26 35 48 70 15 37 22 76 32 59 64 18 25 46 1 72 3 73 12 84 33 68 10 19 56 85 30 45 58 41 82 38 66 6 83 8 65 61 81 60 54 77
23 52 71 47 51 5 49 79 44 14 57 74 13 31 75 43 16 62 78 2 28 4 9 53 36 63 17 11 34 7 24 67 55 80 29 39 40 50 69 27 42 20 26 35 48 70 15 37 22 76 32 59 64 18 25 46 1 72 3 73 12 84 33 68 10 19 56 85 30 45 58 41 82 38 66 6 83 8 65 61 81 60 54 77
21 23 52 71 47 51 5 49 79 44 14 57 74 13 31 75 43 16 62 78 2 28 4 9 53 36 63 17 11 34 7 24 67 55 80 29 39 40 50 69 27 42 20 26 35 48 70 15 37 22 76 32 59 64 18 25 46 1 72 3 73 12 84 33 68 10 19 56 85 30 45 58 41 82 38 66 6 83 8 65 61 81 60 54 77
```

Comment: What exactly are you expecting? What should the shape of the array be? `Numpy` has true multidimensional arrays, and does not support jagged arrays. EDIT: well, they *do* support jagged arrays if you use `dtype=object`, but you essentially lose most of the nice functionality of `numpy1

Comment: Look at `all_data` to make sure it is all strings that can be converted to `int`, then try `x = [int(i) for i in all_data]`.  Is that all numbers?  Then `np.array(x)` should work, producing a 1d array of integers.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I don't know, programming is not exactly my thing. I am just having to use it for this particular work.

Comment: @Kristada673 well you need to specify the output you are expecting, or else how could we help you?

Comment: @hpaulj I tried `np.array(x)`, didn't work

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Ummm...there is no expected output exactly. I just want it to load the file into the numpy array successfully. So, you can say, no error is the desired output. I will do other things with the numpy array once it is loaded.

Comment: ... I mean *what sort of array are you expecting?* For example, is there some default value you want to have when there aren't columns specified, i.e. 0

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I don't know, anything that resembles the original data the closest. 0 should be fine I guess

Comment: @hpaulj yeah, `zip_longest` is probably the most elegant way to achieve the padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pad each row with the max number of columns, you have to implement it yourself. Something to the effect:

```
import numpy as np

def pad_list(lst, padding, default=0):
    return lst + (padding - len(lst))*[default]

N = 84 # max number of columns in any row in the data file
with open('/path/to/file',"r") as f:
        all_data=(map(int, x.split()) for x in f)
        a = np.array([pad_list(list(x), N) for x in all_data])
```

However, for this give you a numeric instead of object type array, you need to know the actual maximum number of columns. So be careful with figuring that out.

Comment: No, if you count the number of numbers in the last line of the data (which contains the max number of columns), you would see that its 85. (My mistake writing N=84, it should be N=85; but not N=165)

Comment: @Kristada673 I may have made an error, but in any event, if you have the correct number it should work

Comment: @Kristada673 I would consider using the `zip_longest` approach. If only because it is more elegant, but it's probably more efficient too.

Answer (score 1):

`numpy.genfromtxt` does not handle variable-length rows. You should parse you `txt` by yourself.

No need to use `array` as following in `Python 3.x`

```
import numpy as np
N = 84 # max number of columns in any row in the data file
with open('C:/Users/hp1/Desktop/ClusterAnalysis/hierarchical_result.txt',"r") as f:
        all_data = [x.split() for x in f.readlines()]
        output = np.array([list(map(int,x))[:N] for x in all_data])
```

Comment: This gives the following error: `raise ValueError('A 2-dimensional array must be passed.'). ValueError: A 2-dimensional array must be passed.`

Comment: @Kristada673 My env has no problem. Do you mind post the `all_data` format?

Comment: @Kristada673 My env has no problem...paste an try again, print the `all_data` variable and see what'w wrong...

Answer (score 1):

```
In [306]: with open('stack44755004.txt') as f:
     ...:     lines = f.readlines()
     ...:     
In [307]: strs = [line.split() for line in lines]
In [308]: strs
Out[308]: [['61', '81'], ['2', '28'], ['13', '31'], ['3', '73', '12', '84'], ['6', '83']]
In [309]: nums = [[int(i) for i in line.split()]for line in lines]
In [310]: nums
Out[310]: [[61, 81], [2, 28], [13, 31], [3, 73, 12, 84], [6, 83]]
```

`nums` is a list of lists of numbers.  Can't make that into a 2d array of numbers.

But with a plain `read` I get a string with newlines:

```
In [311]: with open('stack44755004.txt') as f:
     ...:     alldata = f.read()

In [312]: alldata
Out[312]: '61 81\n2 28\n13 31\n3 73 12 84\n6 83\n'
```

`split` treats that like space, so I get a list of strings:

```
In [313]: alldata.split()
Out[313]: ['61', '81', '2', '28', '13', '31', '3', '73', '12', '84', '6', '83']
```

`np.array` can convert that to an array of integers

```
In [314]: np.array(alldata.split(),int)
Out[314]: array([61, 81,  2, 28, 13, 31,  3, 73, 12, 84,  6, 83])
```

This method looses all the line information.  Is that important?

There are ways of turning `nums` into an array.  For example it could be written into a zero padded array.  But if you don't know what you want, I'm not sure that's worth the trouble.

---

There have been various `padding` questions.  One tool that I recall off to top of my head is `itertools.zip_longest` (Python3 version):

```
Out[317]: <itertools.zip_longest at 0xa9c46194>
In [318]: list(itertools.zip_longest(*nums, fillvalue=0))
Out[318]: [(61, 2, 13, 3, 6), (81, 28, 31, 73, 83), (0, 0, 0, 12, 0), (0, 0, 0, 84, 0)]
In [319]: np.array(_)
Out[319]: 
array([[61,  2, 13,  3,  6],
       [81, 28, 31, 73, 83],
       [ 0,  0,  0, 12,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0, 84,  0]])
In [320]: _.T
Out[320]: 
array([[61, 81,  0,  0],
       [ 2, 28,  0,  0],
       [13, 31,  0,  0],
       [ 3, 73, 12, 84],
       [ 6, 83,  0,  0]])
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used pandas for that problem, where you can specify the desired columns. If a columns has fewer columns, they will be set to NaN.
You have to know the maximum number of columns, but that is easily detected using readlines, split and a list comprehension.